# Compose rgb image from several parts with matplotlib.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I want to compose an image by composing different parts of an images in one single RGB image. I don't need overlaps, alpha, etc.. I just need simple mosaic composing.

As can be seen in my toy-example below, I'm using matplotlib's imshow, which works great if you have the entire image in memory. Due to some other memory-related issues, I can only compute parts of the image, one block at a time. So I want to mosaic the final image by plotting the blocks to the figure as they are computed, without having to aggregating the pixels in one dataset ( the actual numbers are way bigger )

```
text = "caption"
blocks = 8
figw = 10
figh = 10
w = 256
h = 256 // blocks
channels = 3
fig, xs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(figw, figh))
for i in tf.range(0,8,1):
    #
    # .. data is computed here, 32 lines per block, each line has 256 rgb float values .. 
    #
    Y = tf.reshape(data[i,:],[h,w,channels])   # imshow swaps x and y coordinates..
    rgbdata = tf.clip_by_value(Y,0.0,1.0)

    xs.axvline(c='grey', lw=1, ls='--')
    xs.axhline(c='grey', lw=1, ls='--')
    xs.axis('equal')
    xs.text(0.5, -.1, text, horizontalalignment='center', transform=xs.transAxes)         
    xs.imshow(rgbdata)
```

This would currently just overwrite the plotted image, so the question is how to offset the images.

I think I need to look at the 'extent' but I'm not sure how to use it, i.e. what should I use for numcols/numrows and how does that produce an offset?

Thanks!

Comment: You need `ax.imshow(..., extent=[x0,x1,y0,y1])` which places the image inside the given rectangle.  Afterwards you nees `ax.set_xlim(...)` and `...ylim(...)` to set the limits to the full plot (`imshow` resets the limits to the limits of the image).  See [the gradient bars example](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/gradient_bar.html) as a code example with multiple calls to `imshow`.

Comment: Thanks after a bit of puzzling it seems to work. I had to put .axis('equal') after the imshow command for some reason.